# Using upstart for non-daemon tasks

Tags: shutdown, startup, upstart

I would like to have `foo do-startup-things` run on boot, and `foo do-shutdown-things` run on shutdown where `foo` is my own program.

It looks like Upstart is a good candidate to do this, but Upstart seems to be designed for use with daemons, so running `service foo stop` gives the error `stop: Unknown instance:` because the process executed when the startup job was run is no longer running.

Is there a way to use Upstart to execute tasks on startup and shutdown without starting a daemon?

Comment: You do know there is a skeleton daemon? `/etc/init.d/skeleton` should be pretty straightforward and have you set up your own daemon. And if that is too difficult we also have `start-stop-daemon`. http://serverfault.com/a/135882/229730 has an example for a very simple wrapper.

Comment: I don't want to set up a daemon. As per the question, I want to use Upstart to run commands on startup and shutdown that do create a persistent process.

Comment: @DanielGibbs if you're not running a daemon, why are you doing `service foo stop`?

Comment: To simulate what happens when the system shuts down, so I don't actually have to shutdown the system every time I want to test the Upstart config.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You should define two task job, here is an example:

First create `startTaskJob.conf`:

```
# startTaskJob - 
#
# This service print "script start" and end 
description "print script start"
start on runlevel [2345]

task
console log
script
  exec  echo "script start"
end script
```

You can test it with:

```
sudo start startTaskJob
```

and the output will be saved in `/var/log/upstart/startTaskJob.log`

Than create `stopTaskJob.conf`:

```
# stopTaskJob - 
#
# This service print "script stop" and end 
description "print script stop"
start on runlevel [016]

task
console log
script
  exec  echo "script stop"
end script
```

This script will be executed every time system enter in `runlevel` 0, 1 or 6. At shutdown `runlevel` become 0 and upstart init process will run it because of "**start on runlevel [016]**".

You can test it:

```
sudo start stopTaskJob
```

**UPDATE:**
This is an example on how to do this in a single file.

```
# taskJob - 
#
# This service print environment variable 
# start on runlevel 
description "print environment variable"
start on runlevel [0123456]
task
console log
script
if [ "$RUNLEVEL" = "0" -o "$RUNLEVEL" = "1" -o "$RUNLEVEL" = "6" ]; then
    exec  echo "(stopTask) $UPSTART_EVENTS - $RUNLEVEL - job $UPSTART_JOB" 
else
    exec  echo "(startTask) $UPSTART_EVENTS - $RUNLEVEL - job $UPSTART_JOB"
fi
end script
```

I tested it on lubuntu 12.04 and this is `/var/log/upstart/taskJob.log` content after restart:

```
(stopTask) runlevel - 6 - job taskJob
(startTask) runlevel - 2 - job taskJob
```

Comment: Excellent, this looks like what I'm looking for. Is there no way to combine them into one file?

Comment: I don't think, but not sure, I tried but without success, if I'll find out how to do it, I will post.

Comment: @DanielGibbs finally I found how to write single task, it is simple now that I know :) There are upstart environment variables that can be used to know which event or "level of run" is going on.

Comment: Cool, that's much nicer than using two files :) Should the above config also contain `task`?

Comment: sorry, yes, I forgot it.